# Properties of partial derivatives of functions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Assume that $\dfrac{df}{dx_1}(x) = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that, for $x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$, $$f(x) = f(0, x_2, ..., x_n).$$ In other words, $f$ does not depend on the first slot $x_1$.

I know that we can write $f'(x)$ as a matrix, each slot being of the form $\dfrac{df_m}{dx_n}(x)$, so that the entire first column is zero. However, I'm not sure how to relate this to $f(x)$ to complete the proof...

Comment: Do you know the mean value inequality?

Comment: What do you know about a differentiable function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $g'(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @sranthrop I know that $g(x) = c$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I had some idea this is how the proof would work. However, I'm not sure how a similar theorem would function in this multidimensional situation.

Comment: Consider $g(x)=f(x,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ for fixed $x_2,\ldots,x_n$.

Comment: @Chappers Ahh, now finding this in my notes. "If $f'(x)\in L(\mathbb{R^n}, \mathbb{R^m})$ and $||f'(x)|| \leq C$ for some $C>0$, then for $x, y\in \mathbb{R^n}$ we have $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x-y|$$."

Answer (score 2):

Fix $x_2,\dots,x_n$ and consider the real-valued function $g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x) := f(x,x_2,\dots,x_n) - f(0,x_2,\dots,x_n)$. Then $g(0) = 0$ and the chain rule implies that $g'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and so $g \equiv 0$.

Comment: Do we have $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so that $x$ in this case functions simply as a real number rather than a vector?

Comment: Yep, $g$ is a real valued function and $x$ is a real number.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: @mizichael: You're welcome!